# Custom formatting of Natural Number

Tags: java, number-formatting

In order to Learn Java programming, I am trying to put my small idea into a program by reading Documentation and Sample codes available.
Gone through String Formatter, Number Formatter, Spring's Number Formatter etc.

But stuck up to the following step. Plese guide.

Input :(TotalDigits Required, NaturalNumberToBeFormatted)

Targetting to achieve:

```
Input (4,1)      Output String : 0001,
Input (3,20)     Output String : 020,
Input (6,12)     Output String : 000012,
Input (6,179)    Output String : 000179,
Input (2, 19)    Output String : 19,
```

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much, Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) with a dynamically created format string, e.g. input `3,20` should become `String.format("%03d", 20)`.

If you prefer using a [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), you can call [`setMinimumIntegerDigits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumIntegerDigits-int-) to get the desired result. Depending on locale, you'll probably need to also call [`setGroupingUsed(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setGroupingUsed-boolean-), so it won't add thousand-separators.

Here is sample code to showcase both:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(4, 1);   // expected: 0001
    test(3, 20);  // expected: 020
    test(6, 12);  // expected: 000012
    test(6, 179); // expected: 000179
    test(2, 19);  // expected: 19
}
private static void test(int len, int value) {
    String s1 = String.format("%0" + len + "d", value);

    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
    fmt.setMinimumIntegerDigits(len);
    fmt.setGroupingUsed(false);
    String s2 = fmt.format(value);

    System.out.printf("%-10s%s%n", s1, s2);
}
```

*Output*

```
0001      0001
020       020
000012    000012
000179    000179
19        19
```